# Bash: "nl" : what is the best way to get rid of the extra spaces before each line number?

Tags: bash

I have this code:

```
sourceStr="abc
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn";
nl -s ". " <<< "$sourceStr"
```

The output is:

```
     1. abc
     2. efg
     3. jkm
     4. lmn
     5. efg
     6. jkm
     7. lmn
     8. efg
     9. jkm
    10. lmn
    11. efg
    12. jkm
    13. lmn
```

I want to get rid of the spaces before the line numbers. Is "a multiple-line RegEx search and replace the output" the standard way to do it, or is there a better way, e.g., to edit the `nl` command, to change its output to not include the extra spaces?

Comment: The man page seems to indicate `--number-format=ln` will do what you want?

Comment: Hi @xdhmoore, I'm not familiar with what you were saying. Can you elaborate or point me to a tutorial for beginners? Thanks!

Comment: not familiar with which part? The `man` command is used to bring up the documentation for a command. In this case `man nl`. That page has a list of flags for the command.

Comment: I've added comments to my answer.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with `man`. Thanks for your explanation. I'll reply to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed.

```
#!/bin/bash

sourceStr="abc
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn";


nl -s ". " <<< "$sourceStr" | sed 's/^ *//g'
```

Output:

```
Chris@DESKTOP-BCMC1RF ~
$ ./test.sh
1. abc
2. efg
3. jkm
4. lmn
5. efg
6. jkm
7. lmn
8. efg
9. jkm
10. lmn
11. efg
12. jkm
13. lmn
```

Comment: `g` flag does nothing in this context. There cannot be more than one substring matching `/^ */`

Comment: Hi @ M. Nejat Aydin, yes I can see that 'g' can be removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

man nl lists a flag for width.

> -w, --number-width=NUMBER
> use NUMBER columns for line numbers

So try:

```
nl -w1 -s". " <<< "$sourceStr"
```

Output:

```
1. abc
2. efg
3. jkm
4. lmn
5. efg
6. jkm
7. lmn
8. efg
9. jkm
10. lmn
11. efg
12. jkm
13. lmn
```

Comment: I like this answer as it doesn't require piping into some other tool. However, the rest of the solutions are good too!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that.  One, use `tr`.

```
#!/bin/bash

sourceStr="abc
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn"
nl -s ". " <<< "$sourceStr" | tr -d ' '
```

But this will delete all spaces, not just the prefix.  Like so:

```
./so.bash
1.abc
2.efg
3.jkm
4.lmn
5.efg
6.jkm
7.lmn
8.efg
9.jkm
10.lmn
11.efg
12.jkm
13.lmn
```

---

To delete only the prefix, replace the `nl` line with:

```
nl -s ". " <<< "$sourceStr" | sed "s#^[ \t]*\(\..*\)*#\1#"
```

- `^`: starts with
- `[ \t]*`: any number of spaces or tabs
- `\(\..*\)`: `\.` is the point following the number.  `.*` matches everything else.  `\(` and `\)` group it all together
- `\1`: replaced by the group defined with the `\( \)`.

The output is now:

```
./so.bash 
1. abc
2. efg
3. jkm
4. lmn
5. efg
6. jkm
7. lmn
8. efg
9. jkm
10. lmn
11. efg
12. jkm
13. lmn
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nic3500. I'm marking yours as the answer since it is simpler and has more detailed explanations.

Comment: Couldn't the sed regex be simplified quite drastically by only stripping the leading whitespace? `sed 's/^[ \t]*//'

Comment: Hi @knittl, yes. I saw it in shrewmouse's reply below, and, as M. Nejat Aydin commented, we could further remove 'g'. Sorry Nic3500, I think I should mark shrewmouse's answer as correct because his is even simpler.

Comment: indeed, I made it over complex for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of my solutions below instead of some of the others are that they align the `.` without adding superfluous padding on the left. IE:

```
 1. abc
 2. efg
 3. jkm
 4. lmn
 5. efg
 6. jkm
 7. lmn
 8. efg
 9. jkm
10. lmn
11. efg
12. jkm
13. lmn
```

The key is that in order to get indentation that is both minimal and aligned, you have to know the maximum width that the line number itself will take. Below are solutions with `awk` or with `nl` + `colrm`:

### Solution with awk:

This just numbers all the lines with awk instead of nl:

```
sourceStr="abc
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn";

# Count the number of lines
total=$(wc -l <<<"$sourceStr")

# Pass the total into awk, using a HERE document for the awk code
awk -v total=$total -f <(cat <<'HERE'
  BEGIN{
    # Calculate the width of the largest line number
    # using log10(lineNum). Because log in awk is natural log,
    # log10(x) = log(x) / log(10)
    maxWidth=int(log(total)/log(10))
  }

  {
    # Calculate the width of the current line number + 1
    n=(int(log(NR)/log(10)) + 1);
    # Print spaces so that the indentation for all line numbers
    # is the same
    for(i=0;i<=maxWidth-n;i++){
      # Use printf because it doesn't print a newline
      printf " "
    }
      # Print the line number and content
      print NR ". " $0
  }

# End the HERE document
HERE
) <<< "$sourceStr"
```

This gives the result above.

### Solution with nl and colrm:

This looks at the last line of the `nl` output to figure out how much extra indentation to remove using `colrm`.

```
sourceStr="abc
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn
efg
jkm
lmn";

# Add line numbers
results="$(nl -s '. ' <<< "$sourceStr")"

# Count the number of spaces at the beginning of the last line
# 1) use tail to get the last line
# 2) use sed to remove everything except the starting spaces
# 3) use wc to count the spaces
indent=$(("$(tail -n1 <<< "$results" | sed -E 's/^( *).*/\1/g' | wc -m)" - 1))

# Remove the first X spaces from all the lines
colrm 1 $indent <<< "$results"
```

This gives the same results.

Comment: Thanks, @xdhmoore. Your approach seems to be much more complicated than the solution I marked as the answer. Are there any advantages to it?

Comment: Just if you really want all the `.`'s to line up and also be flush with the left side. Otherwise, yeah simpler is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way with column

```
nl -s ". " <<< "$sourceStr" | column -o " " -R 1 -t
```

The option -R 1 to column right-align the number in the first column.

column from util-linux 2.36.1

Comment: I got this message: `Execute a Shell Script failed with script error: column: illegal option -- o usage: column [-tx] [-c columns] [-s sep] [file ...]`

Comment: Sorry, I just add the version of column I use. I get the same message on NetBSD.

Answer (score 0):

using 1 single `awk` to do it all can be a mess. doing it in a chain is a lot more straight forward :

```
 jot -s '' -c - 97 122 | mawk 'gsub(".",$_,$_) + \
                              gsub(".",$_,$_) +   \
                             gsub(".","&\n")' FS='^$' RS= | shuf |
```

> ---
>
> ```
> mawk '$!NF = substr(_="", gsub("...", "\n\t  " (\
>              substr("__________", ++_, int(length($!_++)/++_)))"= &", 
>      $!(NF = NF))) $!_' RS= OFS= FS='\n'                |
>
> mawk -F'^$' 'sub("  [_]+=", sprintf("%#\0478.f", NR))_' |
> ```

*-- too many rows needed to filter …*

```
mawk -F'^$' -Wi '_<(_+=(_==NR)*__)' \_=127 __=10987
```

.

```
          127. wqy
       11,114. xry
       22,101. ice
       33,088. qog
       44,075. ecl
       55,062. cfv
       66,049. afk
       77,036. zzv
       88,023. huh
       99,010. ujw
      109,997. ojp
      120,984. uxi
      131,971. qri
      142,958. emd
```

Extract a shorter formatting substring if this feels too much margin on the left side

Comment: This is absurdly complex compared to the obvious `awk '{ print NR ". " $0 }'`

Comment: @tripleee : cuz `NR "." $0` wouldn't cut the input equally by chunks of 3 chars each (unless they're already pre-made coming in via the pipe), and it also doesn't center align the dot. if that wasn't a requirement then yes no need to make it complicated

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '$0=NR". "$0' <<<"$sourceStr" 
1. abc
2. efg
3. jkm
4. lmn
5. efg
6. jkm
7. lmn
8. efg
9. jkm
10. lmn
11. efg
12. jkm
13. lmn

$ awk '{printf "%2d. %s\n",NR,$0}' <<<"$sourceStr" 
 1. abc
 2. efg
 3. jkm
 4. lmn
 5. efg
 6. jkm
 7. lmn
 8. efg
 9. jkm
10. lmn
11. efg
12. jkm
13. lmn
```